# Ora-00257 archiver error. Connect internal only. until freed

Tags: oracle

Good morning friends. I have this problem when trying to start the connection with the bank by Oracle developer, someone would know to tell me what the best way to solve ... If someone has a step by step, because I don't have much experience ...

Comment: Are you the DBA of this database?  This is an error that the DBA needs to resolve not something you can resolve on the client side.

Comment: Maybe there is no space left on the device with the archive logs. Go for the dba.

Comment: "Maybe there is no space left on the device with the archive logs"    There's no "maybe" about it.  That said, you are correct in that this is a problem for the DBA to resolve.